# Post tags in Custom Post Type not showing in archive with WPML in non-default language

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I've done some searching over the last couple of hours and I couldn't find a solution that worked; so here goes nothing:

I have a custom post type which has `'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')` attached to it. I can properly add tags to this custom post type's item and can even find those tagged items in my archive.php (`/tags/{tagname}`).

So far, so good.

But now I want my "translated to English" item to show its tags aswell (`/en/tags/{a different tagname}`) (I don't want copies of my tags, just new non-related tags for English.

However; this doesn't work! All tags I tagged in English items do not show up on my /en/tags/ page (not even if I leave out the /en/ part)

In my custom post type I've tried changing the `has_archive` key to a few things:

- true
- false
- `'has_archive' => icl_translate('wpml_custom', 'wpml_custom_case',
  'case')`

All to no avail.

**In short:** How can I get my English tags to work just as the Dutch(default lang) for my custom post type so they show up in my archive?

**The registration of my post type**

```
function case_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Cases',
        'singular_name' => 'Case',
        'add_new' => 'Toevoegen',
        'add_new_item' => 'Nieuw case toevoegen',
        'edit_item' => 'Case bewerken',
        'new_item' => 'Nieuwe case',
        'all_items' => 'Alle cases',
        'view_item' => 'Bekijk case',
        'search_items' => 'Zoek case',
        'not_found' =>  'Geen cases gevonden',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Geen cases gevonden in de prullenbak',
        'menu_name' => 'Cases'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'case' ),
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 8,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
        'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
    );

    register_post_type( 'case', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'case_post_type', 0 );
```

My Archive.php just has `the_loop()`. plain and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue! It wasn't that there were no records; I just tagged a lot of cases and blogs and thought the my archive.php would pick up both since they had the same tag. This wasn't the case.

So with a `pre_get_posts` function I can get both my cases and my posts on my archive page:

```
function wpa_cpt_tags( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'case' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_cpt_tags' );
```